# Chromedriver on Ubuntu 12.04 - Error while loading shared libraries: libXi.so.6

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I downloaded the 32-bit chromedriver version on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

However, it won't run and exits with the following message. I have searched various places on the internet but failed to find a solution.

```
./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libXi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I found `ia32-libs-multiarch` package so attempting to install it...

Comment: for what its worth, this is the error I got when I tried to use the 32 bit version on a 64 bit arch

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`libXi.so.6` is provided by `libxi6`. Chromedriver will then also ask for `libgconf-2-4` with a similar message.

```
sudo apt-get install libxi6 libgconf-2-4
```

Whenever facing an issue of missing a specific file `apt-file` comes to rescue:

```
$ apt-file search libXi.so.6
libxi6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6
libxi6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6.1.0
libxi6-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6.1.0
```

This can be installed via apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file && apt-file update  # install and fill the index
```

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan, I improved the answer. But I guess you pasted the wrong message template ;)

Comment: :-). Your trouble was in very short answer just with single line of code, without any explanations. I'm not well with Linux, but I see you edit your post. So, looks goods +1.

Comment: For me on Windows WSL `sudo updatedb` was required after installing `libxtst6`. Source: http://imadethisdesign.blogspot.com/2014/07/64-bit-linux-libxiso6-and-libxtstso6.html

Comment: Thanks @bartekbrak!

Comment: Major thanks for pointing out apt-file. Why have I never heard of this before?!

Answer (score -1):

Try this command, which will fix the minor issues in libraries. Worked for me.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: This issue doesn't relate to broken packages.