# Chromedriver on Ubuntu 14.04 - error while loading shared libraries: libui_base.so

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, selenium-chromedriver

I installed chromium-chromedriver from official ubuntu repository, but when I try to run the binary or invoke it from java library I always got the following error:

/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libui_base.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is not a duplicate of [Chromedriver on Ubuntu 12.04 - Error while loading shared libraries: libXi.so.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924339/chromedriver-on-ubuntu-12-04-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libxi-so-6)

as missing library names are different. And I have tried using their solution which doesn't work.

Any one encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 10):

libui_base.so is provided by Chromium itself, it exists in `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs`.

To resolve issue we need to add this path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Or, I created chrome_lib.conf file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` folder, containing simply this path.

/etc/ld.so.conf.d/chrome_lib.conf:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs
```

Then run $`sudo ldconfig`
After this chromedriver runs successfully.